# How do I tell VS Code where to find my JavaScript files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With Webpack, I can do

```
resolve: {
  modules: ['foo', 'bar', 'node_modules']
}
```

to make it possible to `import foo from 'foo'` without having to know the relative path to the `foo` folder.

How do I tell VS Code the same thing, so that it can recognize, navigate to, and give me intellisense for that import statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need to create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) at your projects root direcotry.
Now you can set the `compilerOptions.paths` attribute to enable [using webpack aliases](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases).

From the docs:

> For IntelliSense to work with webpack aliases, you need to specify the paths keys with a glob pattern.
>
> For example, for alias 'ClientApp':
>
> ```json
> {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>         "baseUrl": ".",
>         "paths": {
>             "ClientApp/*": ["./ClientApp/*"]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and then to use the alias
>
> ```js
> import Something from 'ClientApp/foo'
> ```